# Google Earth API: Listen for TourPlayer Events

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

Can I attach events to the tour like start playing or when it is stopped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No the [GETourPlayer](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_tour_player) does not expose any events.

That said, you have tell it to start playing via the `play()` method, so you must already know when the tour is started...

Also, you could use a combination of the `getDuration()` and `getCurrentTime()` methods to work out when the tour has finished.

Comment: Yes, however I need events like stop or pause because I'm developing different buttons for Start, Pause, etc.

Comment: well you're out of luck then.

Comment: Probably! I will try with viewchangebegin and viewchangeend.
Thank you!